# How to watch a property on a dynamic variable in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a input on a side panel component that is conditionally displayed when a node is selected in a graph. The input corresponds to the nodes name. The input is part of a side panel component. The graph is in it's own graph component.

In vuex, I have a store that has two getters: the list of details for all graph nodes, and another property for the current selected node (or null if the user hasn't selected/deselects one).

The graph is in a 3rd party library and needs to be notified when the node name is changed within Vue. As the graph is in a completely separate part of the page and in a different component I am struggling to work out how I'd detect the change.

In short - how do you watch for a property on the selected node, when the selected node can change (and be nullable?). If this requires an architectural change thats fine I want to do it the "right way" but I dont know what the right way is.

I tried:

```
computed: {
    selectedItem: {
            get: function () {
                let options = this.$store.getters.getCurrentWorkItem;
                return options;
            }
        },
        onSelectedNameChange: function() {
            var selected = this.selectedItem;

            if (!selected) return;

            var text = selected.name;
            debugger;
        }
}
```

Within the graph component but because the selected item is initially null it never detects changes to the name property.

### EDIT

To clarify, the issue is getCurrentWorkItem returns the selected node or null if there isnt a selection. Because it changes, I am not able to detect subsequent changes to it's name property

Thanks.

Comment: Is "selected node" `this.$store.getters.getCurrentWorkItem`?

Comment: yes it is :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `onSelectedNameChange` will not recalculate when `selectedItem` changes.

You could add a [**watcher**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) instead.

```js
computed: {
    selectedItem: {
        get: function () {
            let options = this.$store.getters.getCurrentWorkItem;
            return options;
        }
    },
},
watch: {
    selectedItem: {
        immediate: true,              // so this runs initially
        deep: true,                   // so it detects changes to properties only
        handler(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('selectedItem changed!', oldVal, '-->', newVal);
        
            var selected = this.selectedItem;

            if (!selected) return;

            var text = selected.name;
            debugger;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will that watcher update when the name updates though or just initially?

Comment: Actually, it will pick up **changes**. So it will run whenever an update occurrs, **except** initially. We can add an argument for it to run initially also, if that's what you need.

Comment: `immediate: true`, but then you have to move the function to `handler`. See updated answer.

Comment: This still seems to only pick up changes when the selected item changes

Comment: Don't you see in the console something like `selectedItem changed! undefined --> NEW-ITEM`. The `undefined` means this is being run initially.

Comment: only when the selectedItem gets changed, not when the name within it changes

Comment: Ah, in that case, add `deep: true`. See updated answer.

Comment: Wonderful, in about 45 seconds after reading this I had hundreds of watchers on hundreds of components watching dynamic values in Pinia. Thank you!